# How to push something into an array in a controller from another function?

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I'm trying to make a search input that searches for names in an address book using angularJS but I'm having trouble understanding a problem:

Here's my controller that should hold all the current names:

```
addressbook.controller('addressBookController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.names = [];
});
```

And here's my repeater that should show the names that matches the query from the search input:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="name in names | filter: query">{{name}}</li>
```

Here's the function that adds a contact to the Firebase database:

```
addContact: function() {

    var firstName = document.getElementById('fname').value;
    var lastName = document.getElementById('lname').value;

    dbContactsRef.push({firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName});
}
```

But I also want this to push the first and last name into the `$scope.names` array (for example `"Tom Hanks"`) so my repeater can iterate through it. I'm sure this is very simple to do but I'm drawing blanks and my queries on google come up with no answer. Or if there is a better way of doing this let me know.

Comment: is your function within the same controller?

Comment: @mitch No my function is in an object.

Comment: When you add an object to Firebase (through its `push` or `set` functions or one of the AngularFire equivalents), the data is automatically also available to local code. So if you have a `dbContactsRef.on('child_added'` it will automatically trigger when you call `dbContactsRef.push`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Wow.. I actually solved it just reading your hint, THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is where you do your ordering

```
<li data-ng-repeat="name in names | filter: query | orderBy: 'toString()'">{{name}}</li>
```

If your function is in an object outside the scope of the controller, you can do

```
    addContact: function() {

    var firstName = document.getElementById('fname').value;
    var lastName = document.getElementById('lname').value;

     dbContactsRef.push({firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName});
     var scope = angular.element(yourElementWitController).scope();
     ///OR -- angular.element(document.getElementById('address-book')).scope()
     scope.names.push(firstName+' '+lastName);
     scope.$apply();
   }
```

[angular.element()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) allows you to access the angular scope applied to the element. Here is a working example using document.getElementById():

**UPDATE 2**

http://jsfiddle.net/ck9vdkan/3/

The orderBy filter was wrong.  It takes a string.  In this case, we are using a simple array of strings.  So, we call the 'toString()' member of each string object to dothe orderBy.

**UPDATE 3***
Search added.  'query' is a string property and bound by ng-model of the search box (within the scope of the controller) in this case.  The filter directive will filter items *starting with the" the query value.
Here it is:  http://jsfiddle.net/ck9vdkan/4/

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, (yourElementWithController) represents the name of my module right? Which is addressbook.

Comment: I updated it a bit.  The yourElementWithController is the Css selector you can use like in JQuery OR use document.getElementById().

Comment: @Chrillewoodz see update and jsfiddle.  I am assuming the function you mentioned isn't integrated with the rest of your angular app.

Comment: It works, isch.. But the search field only searches for names added in one session, if I reload the browser it can no longer search for the names for some reason. Any idea?

Comment: This can be fixed with persisting the data somewhere. For example, your contrller will need to read the added data from Firebase in the definition of your controller.  @mayank suggested a service (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) which would be appropriate.   The service would be brought into your controller the same way the $scope is after you defined the service (this is assuming the service resides under the same module).  Your servce would expose a function to return the Firebase data which will be assigned to your scope.names.

Comment: Is it possible to read the data from firebase without using angularfire?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz that I would not know actually because of my lack of work with firebase but I can't see how you would not have such access!